# How to set the tick space on x Axis when we have multiple bar charts in coreplot ios?

Tags: ios, macos, bar-chart, core-plot

I have more than 4 bar charts in a coreplot graph.When the number of charts become more than 3,the charts becomes overlapping and cannot differentiate between the X axis labels.
How to increase the tick space between the x axis labels so that space always remains between the 2 x -axis labels?

The below image is when I have 3 bar charts,then the spacing looks good.

[image: Bar Chart with Space]

the below image is when I have more charts then there is no spacing between the ticks.

[image: Bar Chart with No Space]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the `barWidth` and adjust the `barOffset` of each plot accordingly. This will allow more bars to fit between each label on the x-axis. You'll also need to reduce the length of the plot space `xRange` and/or make the graph wider to spread out the plots so the data labels don't overlap.

Comment: CGFloat xMin = -1.0;
    CGFloat xMax = 0.0;
    
    xMax = ([[[[arrayforGraph objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"X_AXIS_LABELS"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] count]);       if([arrayforGraph count] > 3){
        
        lengthOfPlot = CPTDecimalFromDouble((xMax - xMin) + [arrayforGraph count] * 0.25);
        xMin = xMin - (0.5 * [arrayforGraph count] * 0.25);
    } else {
        xMin = -1.0;
        lengthOfPlot = CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMax - xMin);
    }
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xMin) length:lengthOfPlot];

Comment: i tried like above to increase the xRange but its not working..what should i do exactly??[arrayForGraph count] determines the number of barcharts i will have in the grouped chart and 0.25f is the barWidth...Can you please help me?

Comment: i want the barwidth to not become too small..i can have around 10 bar charts also in the graph..What should be the correct approach..:(

Comment: If the bars are one unit apart, with a bar width of 0.25 you have room for four bars that touch but don't overlap. For ten bars that don't overlap and have a gap between groups, the bar width needs to be less than 0.1 and the offset should be a multiple of the bar width so the bars touch each other.

Comment: You only have so much space available to display the bars. If they're too close together, you have a couple of options to make more space: 1) make the whole graph bigger or 2) reduce the number of bars displayed at one time and allow the graph to scroll so the user can see the rest of the data. For example, if the length of the `xRange` is two (2), the graph will only display two major ticks and labels with the associated bars.